# Using Observable inside Custom Validator Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

so I am creating a validator which checks if the username is already taken.

I have the following Custom validator definition:

```
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { AccountApi } from '../../api/service/account.api';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { switchMap, mapTo, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of, timer } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable()
export class UsernameValidator {
  constructor(private api: AccountApi) {

  }

  exists(control: AbstractControl) {
    // this.api.checkUsernameIfExisting(control.value).subscribe((existing) => {
    //   control.setErrors({ exists: existing });
    // });

    // return null;

    return timer(100).pipe(
      switchMap(() => this.api.checkUsernameIfExisting(control.value).pipe(
          // Successful response, set validator to null
          mapTo(null),
          // Set error object on error response
          catchError(() => of({ exists: true }))
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

This is how I used it:

```
 username: ['', [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.minLength(6),
    Validators.maxLength(30),
    this.usernameValidator.exists.bind(this.usernameValidator)
 ]],
```

My question is, why does the call on my API doesn't get triggered? I checked if the form is calling exists() and it calls it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Async validators should go after sync validators.

So I would try something like this:

```
username: ['', [
  Validators.required,
  Validators.minLength(6),
  Validators.maxLength(30),
 ],
 this.usernameValidator.exists.bind(this.usernameValidator)
],
```

Comment: I'll try this and will get back to you later :)

Answer (score 0):

The async validator must be added outside of the formcontrol constructor.
Here is another example.

```
export class AppComponent {
   myControl = new FormControl('');
   constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
      this.myControl.addAsyncValidators(this.validateStockSymbol);
}
```